# SOAP Authentication issue

Tags: php, authentication, soap, afas-online

I'm having authentication issues with the SOAP server I'm trying to connect to.

I need to use this address for retreiving the wsdl info
`https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl`

When I enter this address in the browser, a username and password is asked. Filling in my username and password, the WSLD XML is shown.

So, I'm using this peace of PHP code

```
$wsdl = "https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl";
$url = "https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx";
$login = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$client = new SoapClient( $wsdl, array('login' => $login, 'password' => $password));
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.nl\soap.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test.nl\soap.php(8): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://profitw...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.nl\soap.php on line 8
```

This doesn't look like a authentication error. However if I download the wsdl file manually, save it local and then use that file for creating a `new SoapClient`, I'm not getting any errors when initializing the SoapClient.

But if I then do a request

```
$client->__doRequest($request, $url, 'Execute', '1');
```

I'm getting this __getLastResponseHeaders

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized ( The server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web server is denied. Contact the server administrator. ) WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate WWW-Authenticate: Kerberos WWW-Authenticate: NTLM Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 3184
```

So that's giving me the idea that I'm running into authentication issues! Read a lot of posts already about this issue, but couldn't find the right answer jet!

**EDIT**
Adding this to the options

```
'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0
```

Give's me indeed an authentication error.

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized ( The server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web server is denied. Cont in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.nl\soap.php on line 9
```

Comment: try link as http instead https

Comment: @MDroid, same error when using that link!

Comment: Got an identical problem...

Answer (score 1):

AFAS still uses NuSOAP (4.x) instead of SOAP (5.x). I'm using the noiselabs/nusoap-bundle which can be found on Github to access AFAS myself.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you get these kind of errors when you connect with Afasonline Soap API in PHP

Below is an example how to connect and request

NOTE: First you need to know some concept about Afasonline API before connecting as you know Afasonline uses Nusoap with Windows NTLM Authentication so in order connect you need domain name for NTLM which is “AOL” in case Afasonline. You can read more about NTLM by searching over the internet. Further you need the following parameter also in order to connect
environmentId (it always starts with OXXXXXXX), userId, Password, connectorID.

I am going show an example for Getconnector with connectorID (SSS_werkgever_vacatures) to get all the jobs but method of authentication is same for all the connectors.

**[Click here to see Tutorial in Detail](http://webbio.nl/wikiweb/afasonline-soap-authentication-issue-in-php-and-how-to-resolve-it/)**

```html
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$wsdl = 'https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/getconnector.asmx?wsdl';

$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
$client->setCredentials("AOL" . '\\' . "53175.Webbio", "Password!", 'ntlm');
$client->setUseCurl(true);
$client->useHTTPPersistentConnection();
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '53175.webbio:Password!');


$xml_array['environmentId'] = 'O12343AA';
$xml_array['userId'] = "41258.Webbio";
$xml_array['password'] = "Password";
$xml_array['logonAs'] = "";
$xml_array['connectorId'] = "SSS_werkgever_vacatures";
$xml_array['filtersXml'] = "";


$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
 echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
 echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
 exit();
}

$result = $client->call('GetData', array('parameters' => $xml_array), '', '', false, true);
// var_dump($result);

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
print_r($result["GetDataResult"]);

?>
```

Comment: Please change your environment password as it has been exposed publicly.